# Express the power sum $\sum^{n}_{k=1}\alpha_{k}^n$ in terms of the coefficients of the polynomial $x^n+bx+c$.

Tags: polynomials, roots, symmetric-polynomials, symmetric-functions

Given that the roots of the polynomial $x^n+bx+c$ are $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n.$

I need to express the power sum $\sum^{n}_{k=1}\alpha_{k}^n$ in terms of $b,c,n.$ Can someone help me, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall: the sum of the roots $\sum \alpha_k$ is the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$, hence is $b$ (resp., $0$) if $n=2$ (resp., $n > 2$). Thus, 
$$
\begin{aligned}[t]
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \alpha_{k}^{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} -(b \alpha_k + c) 
&= - b \sum_{k=1}^{n} \alpha_k - c \sum_{k=1}^{n} 1 \\
&= -b \left.
\begin{cases}
\!b &\text{if $n=2$}\\
\!0 &\text{if $n > 2$}
\end{cases} \!\right\}
- cn
=
\begin{cases}
\!-b^2-cn &\text{if $n=2$}\\
\!-cn &\text{if $n > 2$.}
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: @dxiv Ah, good thinking! :)

Comment: Have you ever considered the case where $n=1$? In that case, the root is $\frac{-c}{b+1}.$ (assuming $b \neq -1$ otherwise the question does not make sense).

Comment: I did after @dxiv mentioned the case $n=2$, but I figured I'd leave this alone. I actually think $n=1$ is a bad case to consider since then the question is whether or not the given polynomial is supposed to be monic (the problem as stated is ambiguous about whether $n \geq 1$ or $n > 1$).

Comment: When $n=2$, it should be $b^2-cn$ not $-b^2-cn$. Because in that case, $e_1=-b$